# Creating a Default for ambiguous overloaded function call

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, diamond-problem

I have a class that has an overloaded method. A certain subclass inherits both of these types. Is it possible to set a default method call to avoid having to call `static_cast<class>(obj)`

```
struct A {};
struct B {

   void foo(const A) {
     /*impl*/
    }

   void foo(const B) {
     /*impl*/
   }
};

struct C : A, B {

};

int main() {
    C c; 
    B b;
    b.foo(c); //ambiguous 
}
```

Is there any way to have the compiler default to a certain method call?

*Clever/elegant workarounds accepted.

Comment: How about declaring `void foo(const C)` so that it can call the default one?

Comment: Oh sorry, foo is a method call from a superclass and C is a subclass. I will edit my question to showcase this.

Comment: Perhaps try compiling your example before posting it. There are lots of syntax errors and the question is now confusing because `foo` cannot be called that way if it is a member function.

Comment: Okay fixed it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a template to do the `static_cast` for you and then call the default:

```
struct A {};
struct B {

    template<typename T>
    void foo(T& t) {
        foo(static_cast<A&>(t));
    }

    void foo(const A) {
        /*impl*/
    }

    void foo(const B) {
        /*impl*/
    }
};

struct C : A, B {

};

int main() {
    C c;
    B b;
    b.foo(c); //eventually calls foo(A)
}
```

But then again it might just be easier to declare a member function that takes `C`.

Comment: Voted for best, great work around. Didn't realize you could utilize templates in this manner without using the diamond brackets. I am writing a math library (with operators) so not needing to static_cast or <> is fantastic for clean notation purposes. 

Thanks